# How to set header value in kendo grid row template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I am using jquery kendo grid in my project where i used row template to show three column in one row. Below is the code:

```html
 <table id="grid" style="width:100%">
               <thead style="display:none">
                   <tr>

                       <th>
                           Details
                       </th>

                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                       <td colspan="3"></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                           
                       </td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
           </table>
           <script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
               <div>
                   <span class="name" style="font-size:medium">#: FirstValue #</span>
                   <span class="name" style="font-size:medium">#: SecondValue #</span>
               </div>
               <tr>
                   <td style="width:30%">
                       <a href="#" class="name" style="color:blue">#: GetName #</a>
                       <span class="name" style="font-size:14px; color:green">#: Designation #</span>
                       <span class="name" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:small">#: Company #</span>
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </script>
```

in the above code i am just passing my model data it's working fine but when i added one div which have value firstName and LastName so it is also repeating with this data but i want to to show separately.How do i show it separately so that it should not repeat with grid.

Answer (score 0):

there is one problem in your html template.

Please replace '#' with 'Javascript:void(0)'.

```
Error:-  <a href="#" class="name" style="color:blue">#: GetName #</a>

Fix:- <a href="Javascript:void(0)" class="name" style="color:blue">#: GetName #</a>
```

Hope that's work for you.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/parthiv89/t0w3ht6m/1/
```

if you like then don't forget to like.

Comment: Thanks Parthiv, i will change the same in my code but i have other issue for that i raised this question.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by own, Firstly i changed code in my schema like this:

```html
schema: {
                    parse: function (data) {
                        var items = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
                            if (data.data[i].CorrectValue != null && data.data[i].SearchValue != null) {
                                $("#spnSR")[i].innerHTML = "<b>"+"Get results for this text: "+"</b>"+data.data[i].CorrectValue;
                                $("#spnSV")[i].innerHTML = "<b>" + "Searched for this text: " +"</b>" + data.data[i].SearchValue;
                            }
                        }
                        var product = {
                            data: data.data,
                            total: data.total
                        };
                       
                        items.push(product);
                        return (items[0].data);
                    },
                    
                }
```

Then in html i used two span to show this value which is there in for loop.
and it's working fine for me.
Thanks everyone.